# Trying to share the video link with facebook but it is showing Facebook App not installed

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-sharing

```
share_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share_intent.setType("text/plain");
share_intent.setPackage("com.facebook");
share_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoid);
try {
        mContext.startActivity(share_intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
          Toast.makeText(mContext,"Facebook have not been installed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

I' m trying to share the youtube video link from my app to facebook app but when I press on facebook share button it shows Facebook have not been installed.

Help me to find the solution.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `share_appname` what is in variable?

Comment: oh sorry that I forgot to mention i.e. com.facebook

Comment: facebook application's package name is not `com.facebook`

Comment: ok. I tried with **com.facebook.katana** but it is also not working and please let me what should I put in share_appname.

Comment: do you have a facebook app installed?

Comment: Thanks, I tried before but it was not working and now it is working. Maybe I was doing a silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`share_intent.setPackage(share_appname);`: `share_appname` should contain the pcakage name of the application, you want to handle the intent. As you said in comment, you are using `com.facebook` as a package name, but facebook application has different package name: `com.facebook.katana`. You can check package name at google play market page of the application (in web browser): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana